# Get Message By ID: Discord.js

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, messageid

I am doing a report system for a discord bot and I want the player to report a specific message by the id so that the moderators can decide if it is offensive or not. I am struggling to find a way to get the message's text from the given id. Is there a possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`fetchMessage` is no longer present in Discord.js starting in version 12, but you can use the `fetch` method of the `MessageManager` class from the `messages` property of the `TextChannel` class.

```js
msg.channel.messages.fetch("701574160211771462")
  .then(message => console.log(message.content))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can retrieve a message by id through

```js
msg.channel.fetchMessage();
```

The documentation is [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage). If you want to be able to retrieve a message from any channel by id, you can loop through all channels and catch any errors.

Comment: Is there any way to get the author of that message? And is there a way to see if the message doesn't exist/exists?

Comment: Well `fetchMessage` returns a message object, so you can just call the `author` property of it. To check if a message exists, just catch the potential error and if the error occurs that will run.

[Documentation is right here.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage)

Answer (score 0):

From the [official doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```
channel.messages.fetch('{messageIdGoesHere}')
  .then(message => console.log(message.content))
  .catch(console.error);
```