# Get specific message from specific channel

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

**Purpose: I'm trying to make my bot check for reactions from a specific message.**

I've read this post: [Get Message By ID: Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442638/get-message-by-id-discord-js)
 But it didn't help at all.

I've searched the internet to see how can I use `.fetchMessage` properly. But unfortunately didn't find any results.

This is my code:

`client.channels.get('CHANNEL ID').fetchMessage('MESSAGE ID').then(async msg => { *CODE HERE* });`

This is the error i get:

`TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function`

I do realise that `client.channels.get is not a function` and I should use this in a function but I don't know how to.

```
Discord.js version: 12.0.2

Node.js verison: 12.13
```

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager
`client.channels` returns a ChannelManager.  There it shows you the available methods as well as how to use them: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch

Answer (score 4):

That answer was for v11, in v12 it has changed to:

`client.channels.cache.get(chid).messages.cache.fetch(mesid)`

However, it's important to note that client.channels.cache may contain non-text channels, if you are retrieving an ID that you **know** to be a TextChannel type, you will be fine but if the ID is being retrieved programmatically you need to check to ensure it is an instanceof [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages).

Comment: I get this error: `Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`. I'm using the textchannel's ID btw

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, it should be the plural ``messages``

Comment: It still sees it undefined :(

Comment: In that case, it sounds like it's not finding the channel so channels.cache.get() is returning undefined.  Are you sure you have a correct ID and your bot can see the channel (permissions-wise)?

Comment: I've tried `console.log(client.channels.cache.get('689781285148950545').name);` in `client.on(ready)` func. it logs it correct.

Comment: That's got me a bit stumped.  Can you try ``console.log(client.channels.cache.get('689781285148950545') instanceof Discord.TextChannel``)  (where ``Discord`` is the name of your require variable for discord.js).  It should log true or false.

Comment: I'm afraid I am out of ideas myself then.  A TextChannel should always have a MessageManager, I'm not sure how that could be undefined.

Comment: Quick Update: When try to check it with a command it works. So the code is right, but the usage is not. I've written this code in my Index.js which is my bot's main script. Any thoughts how to use it, so it'll check the message all the time whenever it's online?

Answer (score 1):

In v12 it has changed and uses managers and added this command to my bot and fixed it.

```js
let channelMessage = client.channels.cache.get(channel_id) // Grab the channel
channelMessage.messages.fetch(message_id).then(messageFeteched => messageFeteched.delete({timeout: 5000})); // Delete the message after 5 seconds
```