# Discord.js Delete Message by ID

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey I'm working on an event bot and im currently working on a repost function. The problem is there are people which are confussed on which post they musst accept so I want to delete the old message.

At the moment allways when I'm posting a message I save the `message.id` in my Database.
I just saw this post: [Get Message By ID: Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442638/get-message-by-id-discord-js) where they told him to use `msg.channel.fetchMessage()`with a https://discord.js.org documentation but It seems like `fetchMessage()` doesn't exist anymore.

Is there any other function I can use for deleting a Message like `msg.channel.fetchMessage(Databasemessage.id).delete()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has moved to the [MessageManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager) available from any TextChannel or DMChannel.

`TextChannel.messages.fetch()`
`DMChannel.messages.fetch()`